# Data over chirp signals

Tags: android, audio

I read some articles about embedding data over sound signals, especially Chirps, like this [application](http://chirp.io/). 
I know that smartphones have ADCs that can decode and extract the data. 
But I want to know, how to embed the data into the signal in the first place? 
If it's possible I want some ideas or links on how to start.

Comment: http://chirp.io/tech/

Comment: yes i read that but its not really clear. what does "An entire chirp is a sequence of 20 puretones of 87.2ms each" mean?

Comment: I would interpret "puretones" as referring to their "alphabet of 32 characters" described in the preceding paragraphs.